# How do I top align this table on my landing page?

Tags: html, css

The table with the two columns under "Meet the rest of the team" just won't go top aligned. I've tried valign="top" as well as  but nothing seems to shift it.

Can someone point me in the right direction to make the copy top align with the images?

The page is here: http://www.rolaa.me/portrait-special/

Many thanks! Carola.

Comment: The problem simply is that before the text starts there is an empty <p>-tag taking the place. (Between the picture and the text about the person)

Comment: You have an empty <P> tag with top margin 25px that is moving the text down and not getting aligned with the images.

Comment: Your Wordpress is adding empty <p> tag , to separate content in post, you can disable it in functions.php file by writing ` remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop'); `

Answer (score 0):

Looked fine when I (in Chrome developer mode) removed the empty P tag between the image and the text div.

Answer (score 0):

There are few way to handle it:

1) with css: add it in style.css file

```
p:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

2) With Javascript:

```
jQuery('p:empty').remove();
```

3) With wordpress filters: keep it in functions.php page of your theme

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
```

Try any one and see.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove empty p tag, or if can't remove apply the below css.

```
    .cosmotable p::empty{display:none;}
```